# Getting SSL is'nt supported in NIOServerCnxn in zookeeper

Tags: java, ssl, apache-zookeeper

I have a cluster with 3 instances of zookeeper for about a year (The zookeeper version is 3.5.8). The zookeeper has worked until yesterday, and it suddenly fails, and does not start up anymore. in all 3 instances.

The exception that is raised when starting the zookeeper is:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: SSL isn't supported in NIOServerCnxn
  at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.configure(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:644)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.runFromConfig(QuorumPeerMain.java:155)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:123)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:82)
```

this is the zookeeper config in all the 3 instances:

```
clientPrt=2181
syncLimit=2
autopurge.purgeInterval=1
maxClientCnxns=10
initLimit=5
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/
tickTime=2000
autopurge.snapRetainCount=10

secureClientPort=2281

server.1=X.X.X.X:2888:3888;2181
server.2=X.X.X.X:2888:3888;2181
server.3=X.X.X.X:2888:3888;2181
```

Comment: Do you have ssl enabled like follow : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/ZooKeeper+SSL+User+Guide
If yes, could it be the certificate expiration date reached ? As it's commonly defined to 1 year

Comment: our certificate expiration date is in 4 of january 2024 but the creation date of the certificate is in 4 of januery 2021. Do you think that after 1 year from the creation date the zookeeper reject the cartificate although the cartificate is still valid?

Comment: are you sure that the whole chains is still valid or only the CA ?

Comment: what do you mean by all the chains?

Comment: we fixed it by running `chmod 777` on the zookeeper folder, and now we are facing a different exception. I opened a new question if you can check it out :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70604009/getting-cannot-open-channel-to-2-at-election-address-x-x-x-x3888-in-zookeepe @QuentinGeff

Comment: @user3927415, I'm getting a similar error when using zookeeper on docker. Do you understand why it solved anything?