# Getting "Cannot open channel to 2 at election address /X.X.X.X:3888" in zookeeper

Tags: java, ssl, apache-zookeeper

I have a cluster with 3 instances of zookeeper for about a year (The zookeeper version is 3.5.8). The zookeeper has worked until yesterday, and it suddenly fails, and does not start up anymore. in all 3 instances.

The exception we get is:

```
WARN  [QuorumConnectionThread-[myid=1]-4:QuorumCnxManager@381] - Cannot open channel to 2 at election address /x.x.x.x:3888
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.initiateonnection(QuorumCnxManager.java:373)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$QuorumConnectionReqThread.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:436)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

this is the zookeeper config in all the 3 instances:

```
clientPrt=2181
syncLimit=2
autopurge.purgeInterval=1
maxClientCnxns=10
initLimit=5
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/
tickTime=2000
autopurge.snapRetainCount=10

secureClientPort=2281

server.1=X.X.X.X:2888:3888;2181
server.2=X.X.X.X:2888:3888;2181
server.3=X.X.X.X:2888:3888;2181
```

NOTE: I did saw on the internet that the config variable for `server.X` should be 0.0.0.0 for the current node, but it didn't fixed it, and it never was like this.

Comment: you can refer this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940981/zookeeper-error-cannot-open-channel-to-x-at-election-address)

Comment: Are you running this on VMware ?